# What or where does 所 refer to in しかるべき所に相談をしておきたい

Tags: meaning

I guess my question here is clarifying what 所に相談をする means.
Obviously something like 友人に相談する makes sense to me however, I'm not quite sure I understand what the example I have provided (how can one discuss with a place).

Would I be right in assuming that しかるべき所 could be used to refer to the police, a suicide helpline, etc.

> 私も**しかるべき所**に相談をしておきたいので...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trapped by one "literal" translation too much. In Japanese, there is really no difference in usage of に相談する between 友人に相談する and, say, 病院に相談する. Xに相談する means either "to consult X" or "to consult at X". Or "to go to X and consult" might work in both cases.

しかるべき [literally means "should-be-so"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61594/5010), and this しかるべき所 has a nuance along the lines of "appropriate place to consult on this issue". This 所 can refer to anywhere where someone in charge formally takes care of your issue. Depending on the issue, it can be a department in your company, a government office, a clinic, or a police station.